# Broken MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, insert

MySQL keeps reporting an error when executing the SQL query. Everything looks right to me, but Ive been looking at it for about an hour now.

```
"INSERT INTO invoices 

(total, generated, account, market, status, name, hash) 

VALUES 

('$total', Now(), '$aid', '$mid', '$name', 'Active', '$hash')"
```

**Error**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, account, market, status, name, hash) VALUES ('499.99', NOW(), 'System gene' at line 1 (SQL: INSERT INTO invoices (total, generated, desc, account, market, status, name, hash) VALUES ('499.99', NOW(), 'System generated invoice during Market setup/activation.', '6', '9', 'Zac Company - Chandler', 'Active', 'b0521f6668cb87de009866b67b25b458')
```

I think this is an easy fix that just needs fresh eyes.

Comment: Could you post the error message you're getting?

Comment: @JohnBupit forgot about it! Sorry. Just posted. Thanks for friendly reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There it is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc, account,

`desc` is a reserve word and so must be escaped with back quote

```
`desc`
```

Also, `total` is a numeric column; so no need of quoting it

Your sql query should be like below

```
INSERT INTO invoices (total, generated, `desc`, account, market, status, name, hash) 
                                          <--Here
VALUES (499.99, NOW(), 'System generated invoice during Market setup/activation.',
'6', '9', 'Active', 'Zac Company - Chandler',  'b0521f6668cb87de009866b67b25b458')
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but even when I just take desc out, I get the same error.

Comment: @ZacBrown, edited answer. Check now.

Comment: thanks so much! I had been looking at this stupid thing for an hour, after no sleep last night. It's hard to find people on SO these days that will actually help, so +1 for you! Thanks!